# Can't call a value from inside an object dynamically based on a variable. ( Reference error: Not defined )

Tags: javascript, object

I have multiple objects set up within other objects and would like to call specific values inside of them based on the user input ( a preset value in this example for simplicity ) but I get an error whenever I try to call those values/numbers I want.

```
let creekchub = {
  islandWarrior: {
    iw2: {
      sb: 850,
      tgttos: 1670,
      hitw: 2300,
      bb: 1985
    },

    iw1: {
      sb: 600,
      tgttos: 1850,
      hitw: 2100,
      bb: 1650
    }
  }
}

let player = "creekchub";
let server = "islandWarrior";
let event = "iw1";

console.log(player.server.event.bb);
```

Is my first attempt. My expected output would have been 1650 however I get a error: "Reference Error: islandWarrior not defined" I tried something similar but with a function

```
typefunction printStats(player,server,event){
  console.log(player.server.event.bb);
}

printStats(creekchub,islandWarrior,iw1);
 here
```

but it has a similar issue, simply outputting the same error.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this, and not get an error? Ty.

Comment: `player[server][event].bb`

Comment: `creekchub[server][event].bb`

Comment: At least that would be the way how to call it in your first code-sample. If you want to pass a string as a parameter to a function, you have to surround it with quotation marks ("string" or 'string').

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

`let player = creekchub; let server = "islandWarrior"; let event = "iw1"; console.log(player[server][event].bb)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).